# Unable to use Google Nearby

Tags: android, google-nearby

Recently I started getting error messages when using NearbyMessages on my Nexus 5 running 6.0.1 and am unable to detect any other devices, and no device and detect this one, even though it was previously working (last week).

```
E/NearbyMessages: Unable to start background listening without NearbyDirect
E/NearbyMessages: Unable to start listening without live NearbyDirect
E/NearbyMessages: Unable to start listening without live NearbyDirect
E/NearbyMessages: Unable to start advertising without live NearbyDirect
```

Also the resultCallback still says success when publish and subscribing.

```
NearbyMessages.subscribe(googleApiClient, messageListener, subscribeOptions)
              .setResultCallback(resultCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try a capture bugreport to see why NearbyDirect didn't start?
Afterward, try a reboot to see if it helps.

Comment: I restarted the phone and sometime later it started working.